# Parsing in Perl a string separated by null bytes

Tags: perl, null, unpack

The **/proc** filesystem contains details of running processes. For example on Linux if your PID is **123** then the command line of that process will be found in **/proc/123/cmdline**

The [cmdline](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) is using null-bytes to separate the arguments.

I suspect **unpack** should be used but I don't know how, my miserable attempts at it using various templates ("x", "z", "C*", "H*", "A*", etc.) just did not work.

Comment: My end result (being able to read the original command line string) is achieved by doing `$line =~ s/\0/ /g;` (thanks to lanzz for the inspiration)

Comment: `my @cmd = $line =~ /([^\0]+)/g` might be cleaner. Then you can simply reassemble the cmd with `"@cmd"` if you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple `split("\0", $line)` would do the job just fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can set `$/` to `"\0"`. Example:

```
perl -ne 'INIT{ $/ = "\0"} chomp; print "$_\n";' < /proc/$$/environ
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't actually recommend using this, but just for your information: the unpack template that would have worked is `unpack "(Z*)*", $cmdline`. `Z` packs and unpacks null-terminated strings, but because it's a string type, a number or star after it is a *length*, not a repetition — `Z*` unpacks *one* null-terminated string of arbitrary length. To unpack *any* number of them requires wrapping it in parentheses and then applying repetition to the parenthesized-group, which gets you `(Z*)*`.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, glad to learn something about pack/unpack.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the command line switches `-l` and `-0`, or by manually changing `$/`.

`-l` and `-0` are order dependent and can be used multiple times.

Thanks for inspiring me to read [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) documentation.

### examples:

```
# -0    : set input separator to null
# -l012 : chomp input separator (null) 
#         and set output separator explicitly to newline, octol 012.
# -p    : print each line
# -e0   : null program

perl -0 -l012 -pe0 < /proc/$$/environ
```

.

```
# -l    : chomp input separator (/n) (with -p / -n)
#         and set output separator to current input separator (/n)
# -0    : set input separator to null
# -p    : print each line
# -e0   : null program

perl -l -0 -pe0 < /proc/$$/environ
```

.

```
# partially manual version
# -l    : chomp input separator (/n) (with -p / -n)
#         and set output separator to current input separator (/n)
# -p    : print each line
# -e    : set input record separator ($/) explicitly to null
perl -lpe 'INIT{$/="\0"}'  < /proc/$$/environ
```

### bundling issues:

```
# DOESN'T WORK:
# -l0   : chomp input separator (/n) (with -p / -n)
#         and set output separator to \0
# -e0   : null program
perl -l0 -pe0
```

.

```
# DOESN'T WORK:
# -0    : set input separator to null (\0)
# -l    : chomp input separator (\0) (with -p / -n)
#         and set output separator to current input separator (\0)
# -e0   : null program
perl -0l -pe1
```